# Copy entire phone to the same device?

Tags: adb, backup, device-migration

I bought second Asus ZS570KL as backup phone since my old one starts to do... weird things. I created full backup using:

```
./adb backup -apk -all -obb -shared -v -f /backups/phone8.ab
```

And later performed

```
./adb restore /backups/phone8.ab
```

But it only restored files. When I checked out `adb logcat -b system` I noticed:

```
04-06 22:29:45.596 10100 10256 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package at /data/cache/backup_stage/pl.m4x.sphinx_customer_android_mobile_app_v2: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/cache/backup_stage/pl.m4x.sphinx_customer_android_mobile_app_v2
04-06 22:29:45.617  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: [discarding file content]
04-06 22:29:45.624  2214 10078 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) adb-restore identical 52 lines
04-06 22:29:45.624  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: [discarding file content]
04-06 22:29:45.625  2214 10078 I BackupManagerService: Package pl.neptis.yanosik.mobi.android not installed; requiring apk in dataset
04-06 22:29:45.625  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: APK file; installing
04-06 22:29:45.625  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: Installing from backup: pl.neptis.yanosik.mobi.android
04-06 22:29:49.671 10100 10256 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package at /data/cache/backup_stage/pl.neptis.yanosik.mobi.android: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/cache/backup_stage/pl.neptis.yanosik.mobi.android
04-06 22:29:49.699  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: [discarding file content]
04-06 22:29:49.805  2214 10078 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) adb-restore identical 100 lines
04-06 22:29:49.805  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: [discarding file content]
04-06 22:29:49.805  2214 10078 I BackupManagerService: Package ru.dront78.pulsedroid not installed; requiring apk in dataset
04-06 22:29:49.805  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: APK file; installing
04-06 22:29:49.805  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: Installing from backup: ru.dront78.pulsedroid
04-06 22:29:49.811 10100 10256 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package at /data/cache/backup_stage/ru.dront78.pulsedroid: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/cache/backup_stage/ru.dront78.pulsedroid
04-06 22:29:49.812  2214 10078 I BackupManagerService: Package ru.zdevs.zarchiver not installed; requiring apk in dataset
04-06 22:29:49.813  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: APK file; installing
04-06 22:29:49.813  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: Installing from backup: ru.zdevs.zarchiver
04-06 22:29:50.296 10100 10256 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package at /data/cache/backup_stage/ru.zdevs.zarchiver: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/cache/backup_stage/ru.zdevs.zarchiver
04-06 22:29:50.304  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: [discarding file content]
04-06 22:29:50.305  2214 10078 I BackupManagerService: Package simple.hexadecimal.color not installed; requiring apk in dataset
04-06 22:29:50.305  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: APK file; installing
04-06 22:29:50.305  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: Installing from backup: simple.hexadecimal.color
04-06 22:29:50.470 10100 10256 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package at /data/cache/backup_stage/simple.hexadecimal.color: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/cache/backup_stage/simple.hexadecimal.color
04-06 22:29:50.473  2214 10078 D BackupManagerService: [discarding file content]
```

So it seems to crash. Google backup only seems to back up 80 of my 380 apps and definitely doesn't back up largest ones. What are my other options to perform *full* device mirror including all apps data, settings, credentials and everything? I'd like to have exactly mirrored 2 devices.

Comment: You didn't state the Android version on your two devices. A guess: Nougat (Android 7)? And what failed where all those apps? Known bug then. If you still have the original install (i.e. didn't factory-reset after the backup), take a look at my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar). Let it generate the backup scripts, perform the app backup (gives you one archive per app), and then use `abrestore` from the `tools/` subdir to restore, which works around the bug (details don't fit in a comment here).

Comment: Yes all apps failed. I used ASUS Device transfer but it only transferred .apk files (without data). Most of apps that had data "failed to install" while I performed cloning but in fact were installed properly so I assume "fail" part was about data cloning which maybe required rooted device? idk.

Comment: It's Android 8 btw. I used _Adebar_ with much better results than my naive attempt to use `adb backup`. It's still far from perfect but at lest some apps properly migrated settings so I guess that's already something.

Comment: Apart from those that failed with a file size of 41 or 0 bytes (usually because their devs opted them out from backup) which cannot be restored: did the restore work directly, or had you to revert to `tools/abrestore`? Oh: and no, data should be backed-up and restored fine without root this way. Except for those where devs disallowed it for their apps.

Comment: @Izzy I used standard restore (`userbackup/sysbackup` + `userrestore/sysrestore`) just added `-obb` flag to script. For some reason `shared files` backup done by _Adebar_ didn't work so I used `adb backup -shared` directly to restore files before using _Adebar_ restore scripts. As result most of apps migrated properly. Most of those which didn't either required user to log in (so I assume those apps had disabled backup). Others backed up partially (eg. settngs didn't get restored but bookmarks did or other weird cases of partial settings restoration). I copied settings manually so now it's ok.

Comment: Thanks! So it was not the Nougat-Restore-Bug (where restore only succeeds if the app is already installed; hence `abrestore` unpacks the APK, `adb install`s it, and then runs the `adb restore`) – but some other Oreo-Restore-Bug… If all else worked out, mind mentioning your device+ROM in #7 (supported devices)?

Comment: @Izzy I think it was this bug if it works the way you said. I didn't mention but I used _Asus Data Transfer_ before _Adebar_ to migrate all apps (without settings) and then _Adebar_ scripts to restore settings. So I in fact used _Adebar_ to only restore settings, not apps since they were already installed by Asus app at the time of running `userrestore/sysrestore`. That said I tried to do `adb restore` after `adb backup -obb -all` having apps installed by Asus app before and it also didn't work. So I guess bulk restore of all apps settings never works. Nasty issue. Gave me real struggle.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now it's clear. Took me quite a little to figure that one out as well. Luckily I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage the system and not give it root access, you neex to use a custom recovery.

A custom recovery will allow you to backup your DATA & SYSTEM Partitions so thst you can restore everything easily and safely.

The most common custom recovery in my opinion is TWRP or Team Win Recovery Project, this would be the newest most common in succession from Clock Work Mod as the most common.

I searched for TWRP for your device, and i got this installation guide... . 
[Zenfone 3 & 3 Delux TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-3-deluxe/development/recovery-twrp-recovey-zenfone-3-deluxe-t3681354)

Once you've successfully flashed TWRP you can do the device clone that you want by going to Backup and performing a full device backup to the External SD Card.

Now install TWRP on Device 2.

Place your SD Card from Device 1 with the new backup into Device 2

Boot into TWRP on Device 2

Go to Restore and select External SD

Select your backup

Restore the backup.

The second device will be entirely replaced with the data from the first device excluding some stuff like IMEI number etc, depending on your TWRP Version....

---

### **Locked Bootloader ?**

Asus provides an Official unlock tool for your specific device at the Asus website...

Here's a direct link...

> [Asus Unlock Tool](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/ZenFone/ZS570KL/ZS570KL_PRO_Android_O_UnlockTool_9.1.0.3.zip)

Reference ;
[www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone-3....](https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone-3-Deluxe-ZS570KL/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: I assume it requires unlocking bootloader? Zenphone 3 Deluxe has factory locked bootloader.

Comment: @Lapsio yes it does. Even if you just want to run it (`fastboot boot twrp.img`) instead of flashing it. Someone said having seen exceptions to that, but those are very very rare.

Comment: I looked into the guides everywhere, and i can't find anything about unlocking your bootloader.. Are you sure you can not just run `fastboot oem unlock` or `fastboot oem unlock-go`

Comment: With a method i used, i somehow managed to unlock my bootloader by looking at the actaul handling of the unlock, Using certain commands before using `unlock` will allow the Unlock... For example the unlock code has this comment written by the developer... "If unlock fails, try lock first" ... So i managed to find 3 commands that needed to be run consecutively to unlock a locked bootloader... The first command ( i can't remember ) it was something like `fastboot flashing unlock` and then `fastboot oem lock` & finally `fastboot oem unlock`........ It will look like the first two commands fail !

Comment: UPDATED ANSWER WITH OFFICIAL UNLOCK TOOL FROM ASUS.

Comment: @Zillinium Thanks. I'm marking as solution since it probably would work. I know about tools from Asus. But I have locked bootloader and unrooted phone by choice, not because I have to. It's just significantly more difficult to bypass locked down phone up to point where it's rarely worth it. (I know it's possible tho, I worked with specialized mobile forensics tools made for police etc. that provided images signed by all major manufacturers. They're actually available to public, just pretty expensive). I do use full Android encryption but still unlocking bootloader opens more attack vectors.

Comment: How do the image's signed by major manufacture's help in any way ? .. You can obtain these images by using the law also, it is part of the Open Source license to Android that kernel sources etc... must be provided if anyone asks for it, to comply with the open source license of Android...... Android uses open source linux and java etc, they can not claim ownership of Linux or Java therefore Android Must be an Open Source Project.

Comment: P.S.. I'm a bit of a self proclaimed MTK Guru so i could help alot more if you had an MTK CPU, i could help you install TWRP without unlocking the bootloader and without gaining root access... I'M currently on a Cloned device ATM, IMEI number, Mac Address etc... I cloned the entire device in every aspect down to the binary code !